# angular-tree-component style node with html

Tags: angular

I am using angular 5 and the angular-tree-component https://github.com/500tech/angular-tree-component.
I would like to style one node different from the others

```js
import { Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { TreeComponent } from 'angular-tree-component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {

  @ViewChild('myTree')
  private tree: TreeComponent;

  nodes = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'root1',
      children: [
        { id: 2, name: '<b>child1</b>' },
        { id: 3, name: 'child2' }
      ]
    }
  ];
}
```

So the Problem is, that the `b` tags are sanitized by angular to `\lt b \gt \lt b \gt`.

How can I pragmatically generate HTML in angular?

Comment: If you have stackblitz sample, Kindly share, we are also stuck with drawing dotted lines in tree view component's nodes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can define a custom [treeNodeTemplate](https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs/templates#treenodetemplate). This will allow you to add custom classes to each node template.

```html
<tree-root [nodes]="nodes" [options]="options">
  <ng-template #treeNodeTemplate let-node let-index="index">
    <span [ngClass]="node.data.classes">{{ node.data.name }}</span>
  </ng-template>
</tree-root>
```

then pass your css classes to the node data

```js
nodes = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'root1',
    classes: ['text-bold'],
    children: [...]
  }
];
```

and finally define that class

```css
.text-bold{
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

---

You could also update the template to just use the `innerHTML` directive so you can pass in html to the name property.

```html
<ng-template #treeNodeTemplate let-node let-index="index">
  <span [innerHTML]="node.data.name"></span>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to apply ng deep

scss

```
/deep/ {
  .tree-wrapper {
    .tree-children {
      padding-left: 5px;
    }
  }
}
```

html

```
<div class="tree-wrapper">
    <tree-root
      [nodes]="menuItems | async | tableFilter: [menuFilterTerm]"
      [options]="options"
      (activate)="onSelectMenuItem($event)"
    >
    </tree-root>
  </div>
```